# What is the primary key of an associative table Joining 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables, table 1 is for patients:

```
 patient_id

 patient_name

 patient_address
```

table 2 is for the visits the patient made to a clinic **(To be changed)**:

```
visit_id

patient_id

medicament_id

doctor_id
```

table 3 is about doctors:

```
doctor_id

doctor_name
```

Now I need to make an associative entity to join those 3 tables, so the table is now like:

```
auto_inc_id

visit_id

medicament_id

patient_id

doctor_id
```

Because **each patient can make multiple visits and in each visit can see different doctors, and each doctor can prescribe multiple medicament**.

So what is the primary key of the join table of the 3 others ? Does it work properly ? Or I should re-design the database ?

**Is there an easier concept ?**

I am using MySQL Workbench to design it.

Comment: What is `auto_inc_id`? What is the expected result?

Comment: The relations between `visit_id`, `patient_id`, `medicament_id`, and `doctor_id` is defined in table 2. Therefore it is not neccessary to create another one table.

Comment: I need to add the medicament not like (med1, med2,...), instead I need to add them separately

Comment: auto_inc_id is the auto increment id added automatically to a table (irrelevant, I will remove it)

Comment: That is my problem in table 2. How to add multiple medicament or doctors visit to it ? I am asked to not add them like (med1, med2,...) but separately. So modifying table 2 is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three base tables, `patients`, `doctors` and `medicaments`. A patient can go to a visit:

**table visit**

- visit_id (PK)
- patient_id
- visit_date etc.

In a visit the patient can see multiple doctors:

**table visit_doctor**

- visit_doctor_id (PK)
- visit_id
- doctor_id

In a visit a doctor can prescripe a list of medicaments:

**table visit_doctor_medicament**

- visit_doctor_medicament_id (PK, if you want this table to have a technical ID)
- visit_doctor_id
- medicament_id

Comment: No. A patient can see multiple doctors in EACH VISIT to a clinic, and each doctor could prescribe multiple medicament.

Comment: so a doctor_id field should be added to the visit right ?

Comment: Oh sorry. One visit multiple doctors. Okay. And you want to relate the list of medicattions to the visit only or to the doctor also prescriping them in the visit?

Comment: I need to know which doctor prescribe each medicament so yes, I need to collect and connect all data together

Comment: Thanks. So it is relational now ? And the relation between them is 1:M ?

Comment: Yes, the relations are proper now. As to 1:M that depends on which tables you talk about. For instance patients to doctors is n:m, even visits to doctors is n:m, while patients to visits is 1:m, because there is only one patient per visit.

Comment: Just one more question. Now the SQL queries will be easier because the design is relational ? Because my initial design would give me huge SQL queries to write, right ?

Comment: No, it's more about data consistency. With your design you could have related many patients to the same visit for instance. And if you wanted to add information on an entry, e.g. the date of a visit, you'd have that multifold, so you could suddenly have many different dates for the same visit.

Comment: `(visit_id, doctor_id)` is a perfectly good PK; get rid of `visit_doctor_id`.  Ditto for the 3rd table.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table .

Comment: @Rick James. Yes, composite PKs are great and I usually prefer them. As OP's design used single IDs (e.g. visit_id rather than patient_id + datetime) I just stuck to this and continued with single technical IDs. But you are right; it is always worthwhile considering composite keys. (Which includes looking for natural keys for me, like NPIs for identifying the doctors.)